# I am making a login/registration and right now im stuck on the registration page on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So this is the code for the register.dart file:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'list.dart';
import 'main.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController user = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController pass = TextEditingController();

  Future register() async {
    var url = 'https://weplant.zanhrastnik.com/register.php';
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url), body: {
      "email": user.text,
      "password": pass.text,
    });
    var data = json.decode(response.body);
    if (data == "Success") {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const AllPlants()));
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) => _buildPopupDialog(context),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Login SignUp',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: user,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                  ),
                  controller: pass,
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      child: const Text('Register',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        register();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.amber[100],
                      child: const Text('Login',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const MyApp(),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget _buildPopupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text('Error'),
      content: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Text("Email or password are incorrect!"),
        ],
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('Close'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

And this is the code for the file I'm trying to push to aka list.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:weplant/entities/plant.dart';
import 'package:line_awesome_flutter/line_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:weplant/detail_plant.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const AllPlants());
}

class AllPlants extends StatelessWidget {
  const AllPlants({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'WePlant',
      theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(
            Theme.of(context).textTheme,
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFEFFEE)
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final List<Plant> _plants = <Plant>[];

  Future fetchPlants() async {
    var url = 'https://weplant.zanhrastnik.com/plants/';
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    var plants = <Plant>[];

    if (response.statusCode == 200){
      var plantsJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (var plantJson in plantsJson){
        plants.add(Plant.fromJson(plantJson));
      }
    }
    return plants;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchPlants().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _plants.addAll(value);
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: const Icon(
            LineAwesomeIcons.bars,
            color: Color.fromRGBO(254, 255, 238, 1.0)
        ),
        title: Image.asset(
          'assets/weplant_logo.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Icon(
                LineAwesomeIcons.search,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(254, 255, 238, 1.0)
            ),
          ),
        ],
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(156, 175, 136, 1.0),
      ),


      body: Padding(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(254, 255, 238, 1.0),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 227, 211, 1.0), width: 1)
                  ),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, left:4.0, right: 4.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListTile(
                          leading: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            child: Image.network(
                              _plants[index].pImage,
                              width: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          trailing: const Icon(
                            LineAwesomeIcons.angle_right,
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(156, 175, 136, 1.0),
                          ),
                          title: Text(
                            _plants[index].pName,
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              _plants[index].pLatinName
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(plant: _plants[index],)));
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
            },
            itemCount: _plants.length,
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:4.0)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It only shows a blank screen when I'm pushing and I have no idea how does anybody know why it would do that? I tried adding the Hero as it was the only solution I found on the internet but that didn't work as well.

[image: the blank screen]

Comment: It does so because you are calling a page that does not exist: **(MyApp())** in the Register page.
It should be **MyHomePage()**

Comment: @Davis How did I miss that, sorry for the trouble. And thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

You need to call class in MaterialApp like this,

```
void main() {
  runApp(const AllPlants());
}

class AllPlants extends StatelessWidget {
  const AllPlants({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'WePlant',
      theme: ThemeData(
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme(
            Theme.of(context).textTheme,
          ),
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFEFFEE)
      ),
      home: Register()
      // you call any class here as per your requirement
    );
  }
}
```